# what is the formula or expression that can be used to represent the selection of atmost r objects out of n identical objects?

Tags: permutations, combinations

For selecting atleast r objects out of n-identical objects the expression is- n-r+1, with reference to that what can be the derived expression when objects are Atmost n? When we talk about atmost we consider the items below atmost too..for eg if atmost is 3 then we'll need to include 1 and 2 alongside 3 in our result

Comment: If I follow your example for "at least" $r$ objects (out of $n$ identical objects), "the expression is $n-r+1$", then you want to count the possible outcomes or distinct "ways" to select "at most" $r$ objects (again out of $n$ identical objects).  The body of your Question is a little garbled, but would selecting zero objects be a valid outcome (assuming $r\ge 0$)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).